# How do I detect execute permission granted to a role (when no ON clause was used)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, role

I just spent hours trying to figure out how an app had privilege to execute stored procedures.

**TIL** from StackExchange: Turns out the `ON` clause is optional for `GRANT`, allowing a role to be granted execute on everything. I had to laugh at the very bottom of this MSDN page after I had tried my best to validate the syntax.

[GRANT Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
CREATE ROLE Test
GRANT EXECUTE TO Test
```

Ok, so that's cool and all (not very principle-of-least-privilege-esque).

However: **How am I to discover or detect that grant?**

I tried looking through all the SQL Server Management Studio login, role, user, and schema privilege GUIs and don't see this type of Grant identified anywhere.

While debugging, I found questions about enumerating privileges in a query and while those are related, this scenario is neither mentioned nor covered by the answers there:

- [How do I determine using TSQL what roles are granted execute permissions on a specific stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244/how-do-i-determine-using-tsql-what-roles-are-granted-execute-permissions-on-a-sp)
- [List all permissions for a given role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role)
- [can exec permissions be granted to a role in SQL Server 2008 / 2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/can-exec-permissions-be-granted-to-a-role-in-sql-server-2008-2012)

I'm looking for the most reliable way of identifying this method of granting (or denying) privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't paying attention to, or correctly interpreting, the results of the query from [Kin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44339/68847) to this question:

[List all permissions for a given role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36618/1192)

In the results of the query, you'll see execute listed but with no specific object type or object name!

Answer (score 8):

`GRANT EXECUTE TO [principal]` is simply a shortcut for `GRANT EXECUTE ON DATABASE::<dbname> TO [principal];`

You can check this using the following:

```
SELECT dp.name
    , perms.class_desc
    , perms.permission_name
    , perms.state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions perms
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON perms.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id 
WHERE dp.name = 'MyRole'
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement the answer by Hannah Vernon:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id IN (
         SELECT major_id
         FROM sys.database_permissions perms
            INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp
               ON perms.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id 
         WHERE dp.name = 'ProdConfigUsers' 
      )
AND name like '%%'
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```